# How to troubleshoot - Azure DataFactory - Copy Data Destination tables have not been properly configured

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm setting up a SQL Azure Copy Data job using Data Factory. For my source I'm selecting the exact data that I want. For my destination I'm selecting use stored procedure.  I cannot move forward from the table mapping page as it reports 'one or more destination tables have been been properly configured'. From what I can tell. Everything looks good as I can manually run the stored procedure from SQL without an issue.

I'm looking for troubleshooting advice on how to solve this problem as the portal doesn't appear to provide any more data then the error itself.

Additional but unrelated question: What is the benefit from me doing a copy job in data factory vs just having data factory call a stored procedure?

I've tried executing the stored procedure on via SQL. I discovered one problem with that as I had LastUpdatedDate in the TypeTable but it isnt actually an input value. After fixing that I'm able to execute the SP without issue.

Select Data from Source

```
SELECT
                p.EmployeeNumber, 
                p.EmailName, 
            FROM PersonFeed AS p
```

Create table Type

```
CREATE TYPE [person].[PersonSummaryType] AS TABLE(
    [EmployeeNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmailName] [nvarchar](30) NULL
)
```

Create UserDefined Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spOverwritePersonSummary @PersonSummary [person].[PersonSummaryType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
      MERGE [person].[PersonSummary] [target]
        USING @PersonSummary [source]
        ON [target].EmployeeNumber = [source].EmployeeNumber
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
            [target].EmployeeNumber = [source].EmployeeNumber,
            [target].EmailName = [source].EmailName,
            [target].LastUpdatedDate = GETUTCDATE()
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
            EmployeeNumber, 
            EmailName, 
            LastUpdatedDate)
        VALUES(
            [source].EmployeeNumber, 
            [source].EmailName, 
            GETUTCDATE());
END
```

Datafactory UI when setting destination on the stored procedure reports "one or more destination tables have been been properly configured"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the UI is broken when using the Copy Data. I was able to map directly to a table to get the copy job created then manually edit the JSON and everything worked fine. Perhaps the UI is new and that explains why all the support docs only refer only to the json? After playing with this more it looks like the UI sees the table type as schema.type, but it drops the schema for some reason. A simple edit in the JSON file corrects it.